# Server Share Unable To Be Accessed On Home PC

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, share

I have a VPS that I use for web development.

I have created a server share for C:\inetpub so that I can access the IIS folder without having to connect to the VPS. Meaning I can edit any files directly via a share on my home pc, instead of having to upload any edited files.

However, this has not worked. I have allowed "any IP" on all of the required Files & Printing options in advanced firewall, however my home computer cannot connect to \\SERVERIP\inetpub

Any Ideas?

Comment: Either your own firewall, or your hosting provider or ISP , similar to [these](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32346.azure-summary-of-isps-that-allow-disallow-access-from-port-445.aspx) may still be blocking TCP port 445

Comment: @HBruijn Nope, port is open, and allowed from ISP

Comment: Ended up just doing a bypass as it seems 445 is blocked by OVH.

For Future reference for anybody who wants to do this.

I set up OneDrive, then made inetpub sync onto one drive (had to create an MKLink), i then created a network drive on my home pc connecting to the OneDrive.

Works as intended, perfectly fine

Comment: Port 445 is generally blocked because it is a big security risk.

Answer (score 2):

Your hosting provider, OVH, is one of many that blocks SMB / CIFS by blocking internet traffic on port 445.

The reason for that is that historically the protocol was only suitable for LAN and not designed for internet usage and there have been heaps of vulnerabilities as well.

If you still want to use SMB to your server: install a VPN server and you can securely access your shares.

Comment: I guess mentioning **VPN is really worth** it here and should be used no matter if your ISP blocks SMB related ports.

Comment: Ended up just doing a bypass as it seems 445 is blocked by OVH. For Future reference for anybody who wants to do this. I set up OneDrive, then made inetpub sync onto one drive (had to create an MKLink), i then created a network drive on my home pc connecting to the OneDrive. Works as intended, perfectly fine